# How do you base the upload path (upload_to parameter) of an ImageField on another field in models.py?

Tags: python, django

My goal is to be able to upload a picture via the admin page, and have the picture be automatically placed in a directory of my choosing. I want the upload path of the picture that I choose in the admin page to use the name of the restaurant in the path. For example, if the name of the restaurant is IHOP, I would want the upload_path to be, say, `./myapp/static/myapp/images/IHOP/`. My current code is as follows:

**Models.py**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    header_image = models.ImageField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        upload_path = 'some_path'
        self.header_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path + name)
        super(Restaurant, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, when I try to run this (save an item via the admin page), I get the following error:
`ImageField has no attribute '_committed'`.

I cannot directly reference the name variable in my header_image initialization because the class has not yet been instantiated (I have tried this approach).

Is there a way that I can change the upload_to paramater of the ImageField after I initialize the field? Similarly, is there any solution that will allow me to make the upload file path of the image dependent on the name of the restaurant?

Lastly, I would like to note that a similar question has been asked, but it is not the same scenario. In the other question, the asker wanted to use a field from an entirely different model. In this scenario, I am looking to use a field (name) to create another field (header_image).

Comment: `upload_to` can be a custom function. Please read [its documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to). It even includes an example that does exactly what you want.

Comment: If I made a function such as get_upload_path(self), for example, how could I use the name field if the object has not been saved yet? I'm under the impression that the only place you can use the field values is in the save function.

Comment: Again, read the documentation. It has an example you can copy-paste almost verbatim.